# Treshold face images in various light

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

I want to ask about some ideas / study materials connected to binarization. I am trying to create system that detects human emotions. I am able to get areas such as brows, eyes, nose, mouth etc. but then comes another stage -> processing...

My images are taken in various places/time of day/weather conditions. It's problematic during binarization, with the same treshold value one images are fully black, other looks well and provide me informations I want. 

What I want to ask you about is:

1) If there is known way how to bring all images to the same level of brightness? 

2) How to create dependency between treshold value and brightness on image?

What I have tried for now is normalize the image... but there are no effects, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm using OpenCV (for android)

```
Core.normalize(cleanFaceMatGRAY, cleanFaceMatGRAY,0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);
```

EDIT:

I tried adaptive treshold, OTSU - they didnt work for me. I have problems with using CLAHE in Android but I managed to implement Niblack algorithm.

```
Core.normalize(cleanFaceMatGRAY, cleanFaceMatGRAY,0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);
nibelBlackTresholding(cleanFaceMatGRAY, -0.2);  

private void nibelBlackTresholding(Mat image, double parameter) {
    Mat meanPowered = image.clone();
    Core.multiply(image, image, meanPowered);

    Scalar mean = Core.mean(image);
    Scalar stdmean = Core.mean(meanPowered);

    double tresholdValue = mean.val[0] + parameter * stdmean.val[0];

    int totalRows = image.rows();
    int totalCols = image.cols();

    for (int cols=0; cols < totalCols; cols++) {
        for (int rows=0; rows < totalRows; rows++) {
            if (image.get(rows, cols)[0] > tresholdValue) {
                image.put(rows, cols, 255);
            } else {
                image.put(rows, cols, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results are really good, but still not enough for some images. I paste links cuz images are big and I don't want to take too much screen:

For example this one is tresholded really fine:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/a1.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/a.png

But bad light produce shadows sometimes and this gives this effect:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/b1.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/b.png

Do you have any idea that could help me to improve treshold of those images with high light difference (shadows)?

EDIT2:

I found that my previous Algorithm is implemented in wrong way. Std was calculated in wrong way. In Niblack Thresholding mean is local value not global. I repaired it according to this reference http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1201/1201.5227.pdf

```
private void niblackThresholding2(Mat image, double parameter, int window) {

    int totalRows = image.rows();
    int totalCols = image.cols();
    int offset = (window-1)/2;

    double tresholdValue = 0;

    double localMean = 0;
    double meanDeviation = 0;

    for (int y=offset+1; y<totalCols-offset; y++) {
        for (int x=offset+1; x<totalRows-offset; x++) {
            localMean = calculateLocalMean(x, y, image, window);
            meanDeviation = image.get(y, x)[0] - localMean;
            tresholdValue = localMean*(1 + parameter * ( (meanDeviation/(1 - meanDeviation)) - 1 ));
            Log.d("QWERTY","TRESHOLD " +tresholdValue);
            if (image.get(y, x)[0] > tresholdValue) {
                image.put(y, x, 255);
            } else {
                image.put(y, x, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}

private double calculateLocalMean(int x, int y, Mat image, int window) {
    int offset = (window-1)/2;

    Mat tempMat;
    Rect tempRect = new Rect();
    Point leftTop, bottomRight;

    leftTop = new Point(x - (offset + 1), y - (offset + 1));
    bottomRight = new Point(x + offset, y + offset);
    tempRect = new Rect(leftTop, bottomRight);
    tempMat = new Mat(image, tempRect);

    return Core.mean(tempMat).val[0];
}
```

Results for 7x7 window and proposed in reference k parameter = 0.34: I still can't get rid of shadow on faces.

 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/b2.png

 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/b1.png

Answer (score 1):

things to look at:

- http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/CLAHE.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#adaptiveThreshold(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double)
- http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#threshold(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20int) (THRESH_OTSU)